# Using different templates with django form wizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I was looking at the documentation and I am not quite sure how to use different templates for each step...

I looked into the source code and it seems that the template name is hardcoded:

```
class WizardView(TemplateView):
    """
    The WizardView is used to create multi-page forms and handles all the
    storage and validation stuff. The wizard is based on Django's generic
    class based views.
    """
    storage_name = None
    form_list = None
    initial_dict = None
    instance_dict = None
    condition_dict = None
    template_name = 'formtools/wizard/wizard_form.html'

...........
```

The docs say something about mixins, but I am not sure how to use them since I just started with django...

Thanks

---

UPDATE:

I looked further into the source code and realized that there is a method `get_template_names`.

I tried:

```
class AddWizard(SessionWizardView):
        def get_template_names(self, step):
                if step == 0:
                        return 'business/add1.html'
                return 'business/add2.html'
        def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
                return render_to_response('business/done.html', {
                        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
                })
```

But got an error:

`get_template_names() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`get_template_names` doesn't accept arguments. You can't just define a new argument for a function to accept and hope the framework will pass it in! (for your future troubleshooting)

Judging by the `WizardView` source, it looks like you can access the currently active step via `self.steps.current` which you could use in your `get_template_names` view to return a path containing the step.

```
class AddWizard(SessionWizardView):
        def get_template_names(self):
            return ['step_{0}_template.html'.format(self.steps.current)]
```

I'm not sure if `current` is a string or integer or what - but one look at the view and you should find a useful "can't find template named X" error.

Comment: Also, see method in accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590759/how-to-wrap-a-django-form-wizard-in-a-view